# How to find Class, Network Address, Valid host address range, Broadcast address and default mask of input IP address (Classful)

Tags: c, ip, ip-address, subnet

I am working on a project on C in which I have to perform a certain tasks on a certain IP address.

I have to find:

1. Class
2. Network Address
3. Valid host address range
4. Broadcast address
   and
5. default mask of input IP address (Classful).

I have been working on a C program but it which can Identify a class but cannot perform the other 4 options.

```
// C program to determine class, Network Address, Host Range, Broadcasting Address and Mask
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 

// Function to find out the Class 
char findClass(char str[]) 
{ 
    // storing first octet in arr[] variable 
    char arr[4]; 
    int i = 0; 
    while (str[i] != '.') 
    { 
        arr[i] = str[i]; 
        i++; 
    } 
    i--; 

    // converting str[] variable into number for 
    // comparison 
    int ip = 0, j = 1; 
    while (i >= 0) 
    { 
        ip = ip + (str[i] - '0') * j; 
        j = j * 10; 
        i--; 
    } 

    // Class A 
    if (ip >=1 && ip <= 126) 
        return 'A'; 

    // Class B 
    else if (ip >= 128 && ip <= 191) 
        return 'B'; 

    // Class C 
    else if (ip >= 192 && ip <= 223) 
        return 'C'; 

    // Class D 
    else if (ip >= 224 && ip <= 239) 
        return 'D'; 

    // Class E 
    else
        return 'E'; 
} 

// Function to separate Network ID as well as 
// Host ID and print them 
void separate(char str[], char ipClass) 
{ 
    // Initializing network and host array to NULL 
    char network[12], host[12]; 
    for (int k = 0; k < 12; k++) 
        network[k] = host[k] = '\0'; 

    // for class A, only first octet is Network ID 
    // and rest are Host ID 
    if (ipClass == 'A') 
    { 
        int i = 0, j = 0; 
        while (str[j] != '.') 
            network[i++] = str[j++]; 
        i = 0; 
        j++; 
        while (str[j] != '\0') 
            host[i++] = str[j++]; 
        printf("Network ID is %s\n", network); 
        printf("Host ID is %s\n", host); 
    } 

    // for class B, first two octet are Network ID 
    // and rest are Host ID 
    else if (ipClass == 'B') 
    { 
        int i = 0, j = 0, dotCount = 0; 

        // storing in network[] up to 2nd dot 
        // dotCount keeps track of number of 
        // dots or octets passed 
        while (dotCount < 2) 
        { 
            network[i++] = str[j++]; 
            if (str[j] == '.') 
                dotCount++; 
        } 
        i = 0; 
        j++; 

        while (str[j] != '\0') 
            host[i++] = str[j++]; 

        printf("Network ID is %s\n", network); 
        printf("Host ID is %s\n", host); 
    } 

    // for class C, first three octet are Network ID 
    // and rest are Host ID 
    else if (ipClass == 'C') 
    { 
        int i = 0, j = 0, dotCount = 0; 

        // storing in network[] up to 3rd dot 
        // dotCount keeps track of number of 
        // dots or octets passed 
        while (dotCount < 3) 
        { 
            network[i++] = str[j++]; 
            if (str[j] == '.') 
                dotCount++; 
        } 

        i = 0; 
        j++; 

        while (str[j] != '\0') 
            host[i++] = str[j++]; 

        printf("Network ID is %s\n", network); 
        printf("Host ID is %s\n", host); 
    } 

    // Class D and E are not divided in Network 
    // and Host ID 
    else
        printf("In this Class, IP address is not"
        " divided into Network and Host ID\n"); 
} 

// Driver function is to test above function 
int main() 
{ 
    char str[] = "192.226.12.11"; 
    char ipClass = findClass(str); 
    printf("Given IP address belongs to Class %c\n", 
                                        ipClass); 
    separate(str, ipClass); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Any Help?

Comment: https://github.com/tlby/netmask